# Поменять цвет select в materialize

Tags: css, materialize-css

Как поменять цвет svg(стрелка в низ) на красный? Испоьзую фреймфорк materialize.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').formSelect();
});
```

```css
.select-dropdown {
   margin-top: 25px;
   border: 2px solid #4f4f4f;
   background: $main-color;
   padding: 2px;
   color: #fff;
   padding-left: 15px;
}

.select-wrapper .caret {
   fill: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <div class="input-field">
      <select class="select-calc">
          <option value="Цвет пластика" disabled selected>Точность</option>
          <option value="1">Желтый</option>
          <option value="2">Оранжевый</option>
          <option value="3">Белый</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```